# Drive N-MOSFET with dual BJTs (NPN & PNP)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt

Please help me out on the following:

I would like to use all 3 transistors as a switch. So control signal for the first BJT is coming from the 3.7 V battery. First BJT is a NPN and the second is PNP. 5 V and 2 V are coming from the power supply, and 2 V is a constant supply, while 5 V is only ON when charging. MOSFET is enhancement N-channel. So this will basically switch RED color LED, based on conditions met.

Is there a way I can make it work like this? Can you provide me some help with the calculation? Would 4 kΩ resistor for R6 and R5 be sufficient? What is the max battery's voltage drop that will still be enough to trigger the gate of Q2?

[image: N channel mosfet as a switch]

Additional explanation: with the circuit above, I want to control the RED LED of the following circuit (3.7V charger with battery cut off):
[image]

VCC = 5V

Voltage on RED LED is approx. 2V.

Battery's + is connected to the toggle switch, where + comes out to this circuit from NC position.

So the problem is RED LED will be ON even when charging adapter is not plugged in. Battery is on switch NC, because it is not supposed to charge in NO position.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147710/discussion-on-question-by-domenico-drive-n-mosfet-with-dual-bjts-npn-pnp); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.